# Automapper - Problem to map class with property inherits from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map from SurveySource class to SurveyDestination class
I'm getting this exception message

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Lab.ISourceEntity]'
to type 'Lab.ISourceCollection'.

https://github.com/abmptit/TestAutomapper

My source class :

```
    public interface ISourceCollection : IEnumerable<ISourceEntity>
    {
        string Name { get; set; }

        int Count();
    }

    public interface ISourceEntity
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceCollection : ISourceCollection
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Count()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public IEnumerator<ISourceEntity> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<ISourceEntity>)this;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)this;
        }
    }

    public interface ISourceSurvey
    {
        ISourceCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceSurvey : ISourceSurvey
    {
        public ISourceCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }
```

My destination class :

```
        public interface IDestinationCollection : IEnumerable<IDestinationEntity>
    {
        string Name { get; set; }

        int Count();
    }


    public interface IDestinationEntity
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationCollection : IDestinationCollection
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Count()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public IEnumerator<IDestinationEntity> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator<IDestinationEntity>)this;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)this;
        }
    }

    public interface IDestinationSurvey
    {
        ISourceCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationSurvey : IDestinationSurvey
    {
        public ISourceCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }
```

My main program to mapp source => dest

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<ISourceCollection, DestinationCollection>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<SourceSurvey, DestinationSurvey>()
                          .ForMember(m => m.Collection, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.Collection));
                });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            dynamic dynamicSurvey = new ExpandoObject();
            var sourceSurvey = mapper.Map<SourceSurvey>(dynamicSurvey);

            var destinationSurvey = mapper.Map<DestinationSurvey>(sourceSurvey);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know that your `IEnumerable` implementation in `SourceCollection` doesn't make any sens ? You cannot cast `SourceCollection`  to `IEnumerator<ISourceEntity>` as it doesn't implement this (and that's why you are getting `InvalidCastException`) ... same story with `DestinationCollection`

Comment: public class DestinationSurvey : IDestinationSurvey
    {
        public IDestinationCollection Collection { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Why it has +1 ? Obviously he should write **right implementation** of `IEnumerable<T>`  (or derive from class which already do this) ... Casting class which does't implement given interface obviously would end with `InvalidCastException` - it's obvious

Comment: I need to map SourceSurvey => DestinationSurvey

Comment: when we replace in DestinationSurvey/ IDestinationSurvey, IDestinationCollection by IEnumerable<ISourceEntity>, it works but we need absolutly to use the IDestinationCollection.

Comment: you can find console application to reproduce it
https://github.com/abmptit/TestAutomapper

Comment: What do you not understand in CLASS WHICH DOESN'T IMPLEMENT SOMETHIG CANNOT BE CASTED TO SOMETHING ? ... **you cannot sell dog when client  wana cat even if you pack it as a cat! because client will unpack and see that it's not a cat!**